# Update column contains JSON with some value from another column

Tags: postgresql

There is some table with columns `A` and `B`. `A` column contains only `numbers` (for example: `100`, `200`, `300`, etc.). `B` column contains `JSON` values like:

`{"First": "0", "Second": "1"}`

There are a lot of rows. How to update `B` column `JSON` values with values of `A` column using SQL query? For example, to make `JSON` look like:

`{"First": "100", "Second": "1"}`

`{"First": "200", "Second": "1"}`

`{"First": "300", "Second": "1"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a strange thing to do. In general you shouldn't duplicate data in a relational database.

But nevertheless, this is possible:

```
update the_table
   set b = jsonb_set(b, array['First'], to_jsonb(a), true);
```

This will only change existing `First` keys. If `First` does not exist, it will be created.

Online example: https://rextester.com/RGNO64902